# If I set display:block on a <span>, is it now a block-level element?

Tags: css

Mainly the crux of the question rests in, is this **DT** valid or not?

```
<dl>
    <dt><span style="display:block;">Dog</span><dt>
    <dd>A type of pet</dd>
    <dd>Man's best friend</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not a block element. It looks like a block, but it's still an inline element. No CSS can change that. Therefor, the HTML is valid.

Comment: yeah - it is just "displayed" as a block.  you could go <dt class="my-block"></dt>  and then in a .css file:  .my-block {display:block} - that would replace the need for the span... although there are php reasons to use span sometimes... like custom fields to change colors yadda yadda

Comment: Not so sure about that... the specs say the DT is restricted to inline _content_. Since the OP has now made the _content_ rendered as `block` I believe it would be semantically invalid.

Comment: @MattK No, semantics means what the markup says it is. *Presentation* is totally separate, but related.

Comment: @kmiyashiro but wouldn't the presentation change the content, or is that not taken into consideration in terms of validation?

Comment: Thanks for the ongoing discussion guys, this is also where I stumble logically. Since the presentation is changing the way the content lays out, should such layout changes be validated against or ignored altogether. A more extreme example would be--> dt:before{content: "div>blah</div>";} Technically the HTML is valid, and if this achieved the desired presentation in all the desired browsers, I shouldn't be concerned?

Comment: Content is the HTML, words, and images without CSS.

Comment: I see, so in the extreme example, even though the css :content attribute injects hidden elements into the content, they should not be considered part of the "content"? Only part of the presentation?

Comment: That would be an extreme example, but indeed, this is presentation. What :content does, is set a text (it cannot contain HTML) of the :before or :after pseudo element. Those elements can indeed be styled, but still I'd say that they are presentation and do not invalidate your page. This opposed to using Javascript/JQuery to insert invalid elements. In that case you are actually altering the DOM, making it invalid, even though the validator would approve, because it validates the source before it is crippled by JS.

Comment: @MattK Indeed, presentation is not taken into account for validation.

Comment: @GolezTrol Thanks, both for the answer, and for the details on the extreme case.